# Why Gant target is executed when one of the dependency failed?

Tags: groovy, gant

This is the content of `build.gant`:

```
target('cleanCache': 'description') {
  ...
}    

target('remove': 'description') {
  ...
  File app = new File("...")
  if (!app.exists()) {
     println "Error"
     return -1
  }
  ...
  // continue if no error
  ...
}

target('default': 'description') {
  depends(cleanCache, remove)
}
```

If I'm running this script, I will get the expected result if target `remove` is failed:

```
...
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 2,21 seconds
```

But if I add implementation to `default` target, like the following:

```
target('default': 'description') {
  depends(cleanCache, remove)
  println "Do default task"
}
```

When target `remove` is failed, the `println` will be executed and the result is:

```
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2,20 seconds
```

The `default` target depends on `remove` target.  If `remove` target is failed, I expect `default` target is also failed.  How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning integer value to indicate failed target, you should call `fail()`.